# Customized regularization function with customized training in tf.keras (TF2) using GradientTape

Tags: tensorflow, regularized, gradienttape

I want to define my own customised regulizer and I am making use of GradientTape. I am making use of the following code, however no matter how large I choose the tuning parameters to be, the results always stay the same. Does someone know how I can get my customized regulizer working?

My model:

```
    inputs = layers.Input(shape=(state_dim,))
    hidden1 = layers.Dense(units = 40,  activation = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5),
                                    kernel_regularizer = sparse_reg, 
                                    kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.HeUniform(seed = seed),
                                    bias_initializer = keras.initializers.Zeros())(inputs)
    hidden2 = layers.Dense(units = 15,  activation = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.5),
                                kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.HeUniform(seed = seed),
                                bias_initializer = keras.initializers.Zeros())(hidden1)
    q_values = layers.Dense(units = action_dim, 
                                activation="linear", 
                                kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.HeUniform(seed = seed))(hidden2)
    deep_q_network = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=q_values)
```

My customised regulizer:

```
def sparse_reg(weight_matrix):
    cumWeightPerInput = np.sum(np.abs(weight_matrix), axis=1)
    penalty = tf.reduce_sum(np.sqrt(cumWeightPerInput))
    return 0.01 * penalty
```

My training process:

```
 with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

     currentQvalues = mainNetwork(S, training = True) 

     loss_value = self.lossFunction(targetQvalues, currentQvalues)
     loss_regularization = tf.math.add_n(mainNetwork.losses)
     loss_value = loss_value + loss_regularization

     grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, mainNetwork.trainable_variables)
     opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, mainNetwork.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: Don't use numpy functions, TF doesn't know how to compute gradients for those. All numpy functions you are using can easily be replaced by equivalent tensorflow operations.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!